# Python: How do i find an equation's value for a given input

Tags: python, numpy, cvxpy

Say, I have an equation `f(x) = x**2 + 1`, I need to find the value of `f(2)`.

Easiest way is to create a function, accept a parameter and return the value.

But the problem is, `f(x)` is created dynamically and so, a function cannot be written beforehand to get the value.

I am using `cvxpy` for an optimization value. The equation would look something like below:

```
x = cvx.Variable()
Si = [(cvx.square(prev[i] + cvx.sqrt(200 - cvx.square(x))) for i in range(3)]
```

`prev` is an array of numbers. There will be a `Si[0] Si[1] Si[2]`.

How do i find the value of `Si[0] for x=20`?

Basically, Is there any way to substitue the said Variable and find the value of equation When using cvxpy ?

Comment: Try [sympy.sympify](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/basic_operations.html#converting-strings-to-sympy-expressions) and `sympy.evalf`.

Comment: @msw Thanks for the quick reply. I am using cvxpy for creating the equation and sympy is not an option for me. Unable to use sympy.sympify on the equation created using cvxpy.

Comment: What is the bigger problem you are trying to solve? cvxpy is for finding maxima and minima, not simply evaluating an expression.

Comment: I am trying to solve an optimization problem using DC Programming.
In it, there comes a time where i need to find the value of g(x) at x=k and so is the problem

Comment: Then why would you need to evaluate the expression at a point? cvxpy should do the optimization for you.

Comment: The equation wasn't straight forward to solve(Not following DCP Rules). So, had to use the principle of difference in convex programming problems(DCP) which modifies the equation at which point, the above said problem occurs. It's a paper written by Thomas Lipp and Stephen Boyd with title "Variations and Extensions of the Convex-Concave Procedure"

Comment: How is the equation constructed? Why do you have to use only cvxpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the value of the variables and then you can obtain the value of the expression, like so:

```
>>> x.value = 3
>>> Si[0].value
250.281099844341
```

(although it won't work for `x = 20` because then you'd be taking the square root of a negative number).

Answer (score 0):

The general solution to interpreting code on-the-fly in Python is to use the built-in [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) but **eval is dangerous with user-supplied input** which could do all sorts of nasty to your system.

Fortunately, there are ways to "sandbox" eval using its additional parameters to only give the expression access to known "safe" operations. There is [an example](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html) of how to limit access of `eval` to only white-listed operations and specifically deny it access to the built-ins. A quick look at that implementation looks close to correct, but I won't claim it is foolproof.

The `sympy.sympify` I mentioned in my comment uses `eval()` inside and carries the same warning.

Comment: How do i tell eval() to use certain value for a variable x ?

Comment: Simply assign it. `x = 3; eval('x + 2')  # => 5`.

Answer (score 0):

In parallel to your cvx versions, you can use lambda to define functions on the fly :

```
f=[lambda x,i=j : (prev[i] + (200 - x*x)**.5)**2 for j in range(3)] #(*)
```

Then you can evaluate `f[0](20)`, `f[1](20)`, and so on.

(*) the `i=j` is needed to fit each `j` in the associated function.